# How to access the length of an inner element in a 2D/3D list?

Tags: list, 3d

This function returns the maximum number of elements of a list, of a list, in a list. I think this is a correct approach but I keep getting the error:

```
'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not lists'
```

Here's the list:

```
list = [[0, [1, 2, 3]], [1, [0, 1, -3, 8, 5]], [2, [0, 7, 2, 1, -5]], [3, [0, 4, 1, -9]], [4, [0, 6, -2, 3]],
[5, [0]], [6, [0, 2, -1, 8]], [7, [0, -7, 3]], [8, [0, 8, 5, 6, 3]], [9, [0, -4, 1, 9]]]
```

Here's the function:

```
def max_inner_list_length(list):

    maximum = 0

    for i in list:
        if len(list[i][1]) > maximum:
            maximum = len(list[i][1])

    return maximum
```

Example:

```
max_inner_list_length(list)
```

Expected output: 5

Actual output: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not lists`

Comment: It is bad practice to name variables after in built functions, as you overwrite them. I suggest changing the name of list to lst or similar

Comment: What is network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to find the maximum length of the list then you can use this below snippet it returns the maximum length i.e., 5 in the given case. I failed to understand `len(network[i][1])` part you can edit the remaining part by yourself. If you need further help feel free to comment.

```
def max_inner_list_length(list):
   maximum = 0
   for i in range(len(list)):
      if len(list[i][1]) > maximum:
         maximum = len(list[i][1])       
return maximum
print(max_inner_list_length(list))
```

I think you are assigning that `len(network[i][1])` to the maximum that is why you are not getting the desired result. Also, one suggestion is never to use the inbuilt function name as variables.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code. 
 The first one inducing the error is that `for i in List` will iterate through the values of `list` which aren't integers. However you put `L[i]` right below in which `i` has to be an integer. 
The second one is the fact that `list` is a reserved name in python refering to the type list. Thus, you should not name your list `list` (or a string `str`) but rather `L`.

You should replace your code by :

```
def max_inner_list_length(L):
    
    maximum = 0
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if len(L[i][1]) > maximum:
            maximum = len(L[i][1]) #I suppose network is a variable
                                   #outside the function context,
    return maximum                 #which should be replace by L
```

Or you can keep your line in the for loop by changing the following line, like so:

```
def max_inner_list_length(L):
    
    maximum = 0
    for i in L:
        if len(i[1]) > maximum:
            maximum = len(i[1])
    return maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to name variables after inbuilt python functions, as it overwrites them. I have renamed `list` to `lst` for this answer.

Currently, you are iterating through every element in the list as `i`, so when calling `lst[i][1]`, the first `i` will be `(0, [1, 2, 3])` which isn't a valid index. You can check this by running:

```
for i in lst:
    print(i)
```

You will need to change your for loop to be `for i in range(len(lst))`, then you will be looping through the indexes instead of the elements, as below:

```
def max_inner_list_length(lst):

    maximum = 0

    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if len(lst[i][1]) > maximum:
            maximum = len(network[i][1])

    return maximum
```

Alternatively, you can use `i` as is, and use that instead of `lst[i]`, as below:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if len(i[1]) > maximum:
```

However this probably won't work as required for your `network[i][1]` line, so the first approach is best for your problem.